# playing radio in background

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, background-application

I just need to confirm if an iPhone app can play or stream radio in the background.

I created a radio app which is working fine.

I want to add a feature by which the user can play radio in a background process, i.e. they don't have to keep the application open to play the radio.

They can close the app, and the radio is still playing.

I read a long time back that Apple has a private API by which an app can run radio in the background, but since it is private, I can't use it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know about how to implement it, but yes you can play music while you app is in the background. It is one of the background processes that iOS supports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS SDK should be above 4.0;
first in your delegate codes:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    if (isAbove4_0)

 {

        CTCallCenter *_center = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

        _center.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call) 
       {

            //NSLog(@"call:%@", call.callState);
            if ([call.callState isEqualToString:CTCallStateIncoming]) 

                {

                [RadioPlayer pausePlayer];

        }           
    };
    }

}
```

then,
I used MPMoviePlayerController, and AVPlayer is OK;

```
if (isAbove4_0) {
    if (_mpmovieplayer == nil) {
        _mpmovieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
        [_mpmovieplayer setMovieControlMode:MPMovieControlModeHidden];
    }

    [_mpmovieplayer setContentURL:url];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    // This is necessary if you want to play a sequence of songs, otherwise your app will be
    // killed after the first one finishes.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    [_mpmovieplayer play];

    newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];
    if (newTaskId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid && bgTaskId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: bgTaskId];
    bgTaskId = newTaskId;

}
```

PS:my english is poor, I hope this could be helpful to you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of these audio streamer for play in background

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

https://github.com/DigitalDJ/AudioStreamer

it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me.

Add following to you app-info.plist file

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
<string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Then in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add following

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
     /* just fail if this happens. */
     NSLog(@"BackgroundTask Expiration Handler is called");
     [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
}];
```